# Am I using useRef correctly?

Tags: reactjs

I want to unmount my a function in order to prevent a memory leak.  I was at first declaring an initial value of mount setting it to true and then declaring it false in the useEffect, but I got an ugly warning suggesting I implement a useRef.  I just want to be sure I'm using it correctly and properly unmounting the function in my useEffect.  To clarify, I am trying to unmount the geolocation listener once the component is unmounted.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"

const initialLocationState = {
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,
  speed: null
}

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(false)
  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({ x: null, y: null })
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(navigator.onLine)
  const [{ latitude, longitude, speed }, setLocation] = useState(
    initialLocationState
  )
  const DidMountRef = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You have clicked ${count} times`
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove)
    window.addEventListener("onine", handleOnline)
    window.addEventListener("offline", handleOffline)
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleGeoLocation)
    const watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handleGeoLocation)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove)
      window.removeEventListener("onine", handleOnline)
      window.removeEventListener("offline", handleOffline)
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId)
      DidMountRef.current = false
    }
  }, [count])

  const handleOnline = () => {
    setStatus(true)
  }

  const handleOffline = () => {
    setStatus(false)
  }

  const handleMouseMove = event => {
    setMousePosition({
      x: event.pageX,
      y: event.pageY
    })
  }

  const incrementCount = () => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
  }

  const toggleLight = () => {
    setIsOn(previsOn => !previsOn)
  }

  const handleGeoLocation = event => {
    if (DidMountRef) {
      setLocation({
        latitude: event.coords.latitude,
        longitude: event.coords.longitude,
        speed: event.coords.speed
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Counter</h2>
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>I was clicked {count} times</button>
      <h2>Toggle Light</h2>
      <img
        src={
          isOn
            ? "https://icon.now.sh/highlight/fd0"
            : "https://icon.now.sh/highlight/aaa"
        }
        style={{
          height: "50px",
          width: "50px"
        }}
        onClick={toggleLight}
        alt='Lightbulb'
      ></img>
      <h2>Mouse Position</h2>
      {JSON.stringify(mousePosition, null, 2)}
      <br />
      <h2>Network Status</h2>
      <p>
        you are <strong>{status ? "online" : "offline"}</strong>
      </p>
      <h2>GeoLocation</h2>
      <p>Latitude is {latitude}</p>
      <p>longitude is {longitude}</p>
      <p>Your speed is {speed ? speed : "0"}</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you're trying to accomplish with the ref? Are you trying to never listen to location again, once the count increases? Because it looks like that's what you're doing right now.

Comment: I am trying to just remove the geolocation listener once the component is unmounted

Comment: Can you show me the warning you got, that told you to use `useRef`?

Comment: Line 31:17:  Assignments to the 'mounted' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: I think you're putting a hat on a hat here. You're clearing the watch and setting the `DidMount` to false at the same time, and then checking if `DidMount` is false inside the `watchPosition`'s handler, which will never be called. I don't think you need a ref (or a `mounted` variable) at all here. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: understood, really just trying to understand the prevention of memory leaks and ensuring im not constantly listening for the user's location in the background

Comment: The `useEffect`'s cleanup should take care of that. Although, beware that if the handle function isn't pure (if it depends on state or props or etc) you might remove a different listener and then you might have a leak. In your case, everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments:

```
  const DidMountRef = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }
```

Technically speaking the component is not mounted until the `useEffect` callback has been called. But that doesn't seem to affect the logic in your example too much.

---

```
  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleGeoLocation)
    const watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handleGeoLocation)
    return () => {
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId)
      DidMountRef.current = false
    }
  }, [count])
```

I don't think your really want `[count]` as a hook dependency. If all you want is for the effect to be called on mount/unmount you should provide `[]` as dependencies. From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects):

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument.

---

I don't really understand why you guard within `handleGeoLocation`:

```
  const handleGeoLocation = event => {
    if (DidMountRef) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

This code should work:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleGeoLocation)
    const watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handleGeoLocation)
    return () => {
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId)
    }
  }, [])

  const handleGeoLocation = event => {
    setLocation({
      latitude: event.coords.latitude,
      longitude: event.coords.longitude,
      speed: event.coords.speed
    })
  }
```